# Most efficient way to handle big number of constants

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

I am writing a program that, depending on a certain values from an Excel table, makes an API call. There are 2 conditions from the table that will be checked:

- Language
- Provider

Depending on those two values a different set of constants is needed for the API call:

```
def run_workflow(provider, language, workflow):

    if provider == 'xxxx' and language == 0:

    wf_ready = provider_ready
    wf_unverified = provider_unverified
    wf_active = provider_active
    wf_another = provider_another
    wf_closed = provider_closed
    wf_wrongid = provider_wrongid

    elif provider == 'yyyy' and language == 0:

    wf_ready = provider_ready
    wf_unverified = provider_unverified
    wf_active = provider_active
    wf_another = provider_another
    wf_closed = provider_closed
    wf_wrongid = provider_wrongid

    elif ...


    if workflow == 'ready':
    response = requests.post(API + wf_ready),headers=header, data=json.dumps(conversation))

    elif workflow == 'unverified':
    response = requests.post(API + wf_unverified),headers=header, data=json.dumps(conversation))

    elif ...
```

There are 2 provider and 7 different languages and I am trying to figure out the most efficient (and Pythonic way) to handle this scenario and came up with creating a class for each language:

```
class Workflow_Language():

  def english(self):

    self.provider_unverified = 1112
    self.provider_ready = 1113
    self.provider_active = 1114
    self.provider_vip = 1115

  def russian(self):

    self.provider_unverified = 1116
    self.provider_ready = 1117
    self.provider_active = 1118
    self.provider_vip = 1119

  def ...
```

...

Is there maybe a better way to handle this?

Comment: Maybe read these values from some kind of config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to map constants to appropriate handlers:

```
class LanguageData:
    def __init__(self, unverified, ready, active, vip):
        self.unverified = unverified
        self.ready = ready
        self.active = active
        self.vip = vip

def english():
    return LanguageData(1,2,3,4)

def russian():
    return LanguageData(5,6,7,8)

LANGUAGE_MAP = {'en': english, 'ru': russian}
```

I've made up `'en', 'ru'` values for clarity. It seems that `0` is in your case? Also note that `english` and `russian` are standalone functions. Finally the `LanguageData` class is not mandatory, you can simply return a dictionary from those functions. But workin with attributes instead of string keys seems easier to maintain.

And then in the code:

```
def run_workflow(provider, language, workflow):
    lang_data = LANGUAGE_MAP[language]()
    if workflow == 'ready':
        url = API + data.ready
    elif workflow == 'unverified':
        url = API + data.unverified
    response = requests.post(url, headers=header, data=json.dumps(conversation))
```

Of course `workflow` can be wrapped in a similar way if there are more than 2 possible values.

Analogously for `provider`. Unless the action depends on both `provider` and `language` at the same time in which case you need a double map:

```
LANG_PROV_MAP = {
    ('en', 'xxxx'): first,
    ('ru', 'yyyy'): second,
}
def run_workflow(provider, language, workflow):
    data = LANG_PROV_MAP[(provider, language)]()
    ...
```

The original code can be simplified with a tricky decorator:

```
LANGUAGE_MAP = {}
def language_handler(lang):
    def wrapper(fn):
        LANGUAGE_MAP[lang] = fn
        return fn
    return wrapper

@language_handler('en')
def handler():
    return LanguageData(1,2,3,4)

@language_handler('ru')
def handler():
    return LanguageData(5,6,7,8)
```

Also note that if the data is "constant" (i.e. doesn't depend on the context) then you can completely omit callables to make everything even simplier:

```
LANGUAGE_MAP = {
    'en': LanguageData(1,2,3,4),
    'ru': LanguageData(5,6,7,8),
}
def run_workflow(provider, language, workflow):
    data = LANGUAGE_MAP[language]
    ...
```

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've added to my answer that using dictionaries is a possibility. But working with string keys is often harder than working with attributes. And I advice using classes. For starters most IDE nowadays support classes nicely unlike arbitrary dictionaries. Classes also play well with modern hinting and static analysis.

Comment: Indeed - but a dict can be more easily used to pass as keywords args or as parameters (get or post) for a request. Now you can of course also add a `to_dict` method to the class...

Comment: @freakish Thanks a lot! This already helped me a lot. However, I did not mention that I have to check for the language and the provider at the same time. So, I have 2 provider and for each provider there would be 2 sets of workflows(constants) for each language. Still not sure which might be the best solution for this scenario. Currently I think simply using two maps (LANGUAGE_MAP_PROVIDER1 and LANGUAGE_MAP_PROVIDER2) might best? Since the data is constant I would skip the callables like you showed in your last example, but with two maps then?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of the language and provider can compose the method name and the call will be invoked dynamically.

Example:

```
import sys

def provider1_lang2():
    pass

def provider2_lang4():
    pass

 # get the provider / lang and call the method dynamically
 provider = 'provider2'
 lang = 'lang4' 
 method_name = '{}_{}'.format(provider,lang)
 method =  getattr(sys.modules[__name__], method_name)
 method()
```

Comment: better use a dict - that's more explicit, less error-prone, easier to read and maintain etc.